# How to add a bar button item in interface builder?

Tags: xcode, interface-builder

I am really new to iPhone development and I need help setting up my views.

I have a view that is named `FirstViewController.xib` and a controller class for this view.

In my `MainWindox.xib` I have setup a root controller with a `moveToNextView` function that is connected to the options bar button item.

So when I click on this item the current view switches to the first view and I am able to swticht back. That works fine so far.

The navigation bar at the top of the screen from the `MainWindow.xib` is displayed in the first view, too. But when I open `FirstViewController.xib` there isn't any navigation bar defined (but on build&run it is displayed).

This is a problem for me because I want to add a save bar item to the first view. How do I solve that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to do it from code. Add to your FirstViewController class `viewDidLoad` method:

```
  UIBarButtonItem *anotherButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Save" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:@selector(doSave:)];
  self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = anotherButton;
  [anotherButton release];
```

Answer (score 19):

Assuming you have a UIViewController (or UIViewController subclass) that is a child of a UINavigationController. Note, I'm using storyboards so your results may vary when using xibs.

- If you do not see a UINavigationBar on the interface, try manually changing the simulated metrics.
- Drag a Navigation Item onto the view (anywhere). You should now have a place to enter the title in the interface builder.

[image: Simulated Metrics]

- Now you can drag Bar Button Items onto the nav bar.

[image]

Comment: This is a xib question, not a storyboard question.

Answer (score 3):

Just drag a bar button item onto your nav bar in Interface Builder.  Xcode automatically wires it up then you can use it like anything else...

Comment: That works as expected when working with a storyboard. It doesn't work on standalone view controller XIBs.  I converted our app from storyboard to XIB - have to support iOS4 - and this is one thing that's really confusing.

Comment: does not work on Xcode 6. This is Apple making our lives easy.

Comment: It will only work if you have already dragged a navigation item onto the view. See my answer