# Is there a way to show UINavigationController in the second storyboard if that UINavigationController in the first storyboard?

Tags: swift, xcode, ipad, uinavigationcontroller, storyboard

I have the first storyboard has UINavigationController its continues to the second storyboard but it doesn't appear there only when running the app.

I link between storyboard by (Storyboard Reference)

[The first storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Jzsa.png)

[The second storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kmnAt.png)

The UINavigationController doesn't appear in the second storyboard its appear only when running the app.

Comment: Seems Storyboard glitch. Nothing to bother.

Comment: I need to edit the UINavigationController item in the storyboard.

Comment: If the changes are specific to second storyboard viewControllers then you can do it programmatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is normal behaviour of the Storyboard as the controller in your second storyboard does not know if it is a controller in a navigation controller, hence it does not show the navigation bar. If yo want to show the navigation bar in the storyboard you can select it in the Simulated Metrics in the Attributes Inspector (shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7jOrf.png) in that [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5336468/how-to-add-a-bar-button-item-in-interface-builder)). You can see it working by giving the controller a title for example.

Comment: It appears but not like the main navigation controller style.

Answer (score 0):

according to navigation controllers property it will not show the navigation bar in your case , if you want to edit or customise navigation items or navigationbar then you have to make changes programatically .

but to make changes in navigationbar or navigation items there is some limitations sometimes you can't fully customise it and sometimes you customise it depend on your requirement ... :(

> I suggest you that use navigation property but hide the navigation bar
>   and on place of navigation bar (on top of every view controller) set a
>   view which will look like navigation bar and you can easily customise
>   it as per your requirement .

Comment: that is not an efficient way to do it.